# When opening Logic Apps: An unknown error occured (Code 502)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

When I try to open a Logic App Ressouce I get the following error message:

[image: { "shellProps": { "sessionId": "9705bf106599432cb5a7f25118fa740f", "extName": "Microsoft_Azure_EMA", "contentName": "WorkflowResourceBlade", "resourceId": "/subscriptions/3dce6ad6-775e-4319-9699-5558638ac38e/resourceGroups/ba-iot/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/ba-iot-alert" }, "error": { "message": "An unknown error occurred.", "code": 502 }}]

When I reload the page multiple times it works sometimes, but just for the moment. As soon as I try to edit or run a logic app, I get the same error.

Already looked at the health status and logic app logs. But without any results.

**Does anybody have a solution for this?**

Answer (score 0):

I have been in contact with Azure Support regarding the same issue and according to them there is an issue in West Europe that is causing this. **A workaround is to use another region if applicable.** I have been able to use Central US without any issue.